# I have an issue in System.out.println

Tags: java

i have a situation where firstly i used System.out.println() in all the places in my project now it is decided in place of SOP log into the file is it possible to override the println() method in one place and apply at all the classes.in short no need to change in every classes.

Comment: Use a regex search and replace? Another good reason to write logging in early.

Comment: It's a good practice to encapsulate the console printing into a class you can later update to use, for example, Log4j. This implies refactoring, I know, but an IDE should help you with that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you need but you can redirect standard output stream to another `PrintStram` with

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream("yourLogFile.log"));
```

Comment: Was totally unaware of this. Incredibly useful. Thanks.

Comment: While this is an option, I would imagine it goes against the spirit of the change request. That is, to have logging, with all the attendant niceties of log levels and the ability to modify run time behavior.

Comment: Yes it is not exactly what OP probably want but rather an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

No, `System` class is in package `java.lang`, and you can't override classes in this package. You need to do refactoring in your project.